# Cef Sharp.wpf Issue with windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

When we are running my application on the window 10 then it's refreshing or (glitching) after 2 or 3 second. We are using 
CefSharp.Wpf 49.0.1  Version. And also we are using modern ui in my project so when we press backspace key then its sending on previous user control. we can fix this?

Comment: Read the release notes for know issues. One question at a time please.

Comment: Hi have you any idea for prevent "refreshing or (glitching) after 2 or 3 second with window 10"

Comment: As I've already said, read the release notes for known issues. They're on `GitHub`.